# Remove custom options only from cart item

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cart, custom-options, quoteitem

I want to remove only the custom options added with the cart item without removing the product. Is there any solution for this? I am using Magento 2.3.4 version.

Comment: Do you want to remove options as I mentioned in the screenshot? https://prnt.sc/zujpbf

Comment: @ZealousWeb is this attributes added as custom option OR config product option? i think in the screenshot it is a configurable product and size and color are the attributes.
I want to remove the custom option selected for a cart item.